# converting 110V chandelier to 220V

Tags: light-fixture

I have a Kathy Ireland chandelier bought in the US with 110V.  Can I use this chandelier in the Philippines having 220V Electricity?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

The bulbs required for most chandeliers are either the candelabra type, or Edison base type.  Just need to order some rated @ 220v.  Rewiring the chandelier is not necessary.

If using a dimmer, take note of the dimmers maximum wattage rating which here in the US are usually rated at 600 watts. 10 bulbs x 40 watt is 400 watts regardless if the voltage is 120V or 240V.